# How to display JavaScript confirmation dialog box AND run a function in GridView C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

When I delete a GridView row, I want to display JavaScript confirmation dialog box AND run a function.
How do you do that?

Something like that:

```
protected void GridViewActivities_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1");
            lb.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return confirm('You are sure?'); + MyFunction()");
        }
    }
```

Comment: With the code above, does the confirmation appear and work?

Comment: the code you add for onclick event doesn't seem to be correct javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your function based on confirmation box result, try this code

```
protected void GridViewActivities_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1");
            lb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "var result = confirm('You are sure?'); if(result) { MyFunction(); } return true; ");
        }
    }
```

If you want to run your function irrespective of the confirmation box result, try this code:

```
protected void GridViewActivities_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1");
            lb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "confirm('You are sure?'); MyFunction(); return true; ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's more correct to return result instead of true, otherwise the postback of the linkbutton would also run when the user answers the confirmation with no/false.

Comment: Well it depends what the requirements are. In the question the only requirement was to call the custom function after confirmation box.